# Shared MVC Razor functions in several views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, razor

I have functions in my view that is shared by several pages:

```
@functions 
{
    public HtmlString ModeImage(ModeEnum mode) 
    {
        switch(mode)
        {
            case AMode: new HtmlString("<img etc..."); break;
            // more etc...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to have it in a separate file and include it on each page without having to copy and paste it in to each one. I know I can write a .cs file and access it per page, but the function really concerns the view and I'de hate to have to recompile if this function changes.

Comment: What's wrong with recompiling?

Comment: what about putting this function inside Layout view

Comment: @Miro: That won't work.  Pages don't inherit anything from their layout pages.  After all, `Layout` is set at runtime.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602507/using-a-razor-functions-in-several-webpages-cshtml-files if you really need to reuse the same function over several distinct views.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This sounds like you want the Razor @helper methods described in the blog post [ASP.NET MVC3 and the @helper syntax within Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx)  by Scott Guthrie.

Here is the overview...
*"The @helper syntax within Razor enables you to easily create re-usable helper methods that can encapsulate output functionality within your view templates.  They enable better code reuse, and can also facilitate more readable code."*

Comment: It doesn't look like he wants a helper (he's returning void)

Comment: Sorry, it is sort of a helper method which returns an image html depending on an enum. I feel like its too little for a partial and  I don't want code to be recompiled if I say, change the icon name. This looks like what I'm looking for. Going to try it out first.

Comment: That was perfect. =) I didn't know this existed. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is useful, but helpers have some limitations such as lack of generics, and you can still reuse static methods across multiple views.

Answer (score 46):

(Here's a more detailed version of the existing answers.)

Create a folder called `App_Code` in the root of the MVC project if it doesn't already exist. In here, create an empty razor view and name it whatever you want:

[image: MVC project with Razor view called Shared.cshtml inside App_Code folder]

Add `@helper`s and/or `static` methods to it as needed:

```
@helper ShowSomething()
{
    <span>Something</span>
}

@functions
{
    public static int CalculateSomething()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Then use them from your views by first accessing the shared view by name:

```
@Shared.ShowSomething()
@Shared.CalculateSomething()
```

Comment: That's awesome. Can you do the same for an Area? Basically, not shared across the whole codebase, but rather just one section?

Comment: @twsmale, I don't know; I haven't really used areas before. Maybe you could make a new question for that.

Comment: up for explaining in detail about the difference between helper and functions and the way to use them

Comment: now, we cannot share functions in dotnet core `.net6`  like this

Answer (score 4):

You could make a [static helper page](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/03/dissecting-razor-part-8-static-helpers.html) and put a normal `static` method in the page.
You could then call it by writing `PageName.MyMethod()` anywhere, and I believe that you won't need to recompile the project.