# Using a Razor @functions in several webpages (.cshtml files)

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-webpages

I have the below function that I would like to be available to several .cshtml views in my asp.net web pages 2 application. How can I make this function available to any view in the application (as opposed to just one).

```
@functions {

    public bool DisplayButton(String startDate, String endDate)
    {
        return Convert.ToDateTime(startDate) < DateTime.Now && Convert.ToDateTime(endDate) > DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347447/shared-mvc-razor-functions-in-several-views

Comment: I'm not trying to use a helper.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Create a file called Functions.cshtml in App_Code and then paste the code you have into the file. Then you can call the DisplayButton method in any .cshtml file by prefixing it with the file name:

```
var myBool = Functions.DisplayButton(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(30));
```

For more on working with functions and helpers in ASP.NET Web Pages, read this: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/173/The-Difference-Between-@Helpers-and-@Functions-In-WebMatrix

Comment: I have this error message.
CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Functions.AgoDateString()'

Comment: This works. As the linked article says the files Functions.cshtml may be called anything, but the methods declared must be public static, and they're called by referencing the file name @Functions.MyMethod(). If the methods are not public static you will receive a similar error to Georgi. Also note that MSVC autogenerates the required classes for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can define "global" helper functions in a Razor file in the AppCode directory as described here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx.  However, helpers only render page elements; they cannot return a value (or more correctly, the returned value is the HTML markup to be rendered).

If you need to return a value, your best bet is an extension method.

Comment: The functions keyword is used to define a function (method) that returns a value defined by the method signature. The helper keyword defines a Razor template that renders HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Don't see why you couldn't have a static class with a static method and just include it at the top of every view and then use it

Comment: because you'll need to compile every time you modify the class